# How to Rotate Camera only once

Tags: unity

I have a simple camera rotate script which rotates the camera around my game scene

i only want it to do it once at the start to show off the level

or how can i rotate it a whole 360 degrees then stop?

How can i achieve this?

My camera rotate script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CamRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to stop it?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 i dont know how to, Im confused

Answer (score 0):

This is very trivial. If you're finding that this task is a blocker for you, then you should definitely consider putting your game aside and working through some beginner Unity tutorials to practice the basics like this.

```
// Create a coroutine that can stretch over
// several frames, starting automatically
// when the object spawns.
IEnumerator Start() {

    // Cache the orientation of the object.
    Quaternion originalOrientation = transform.rotation;

    // Loop until we hit 360 degrees.
    for (float degrees = 0; 
           degrees < 360f; 
           degrees += Time.deltaTime * speed
    ) {
        // Rotate our original pose by this angle.
        Quaternion yaw = Quaternion.Euler(0, degrees, 0);
        transform.rotation = yaw * originalOrientation;

        // Wait one frame, then resume the loop.
        yield return null;
    }

    // Return exactly to our initial pose.
    transform.rotation = originalOrientation;
}
```